# Adding button to R pie chart for toggle between values to percent

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I need to how to add a button to switch from percent to value in the following pie, actually I added both values; but I need to toggle between.

Any body have an idea how to do it?

That's the code I actually have for one pie.

Any help is welcome.

```
output$t <- renderPlotly({
    data<-dt()%>%
      group_by(Type)%>%
      summarise(sum = sum(Premium)/1000000)%>%
      plot_ly(labels = ~Type,
              textinfo='percent+value',
              textfont = list(color = "black"),
              values = ~format(sum, nsmall = 2, digits = 2),
              marker = list(colors = color_product),
              sort = FALSE
      )%>%
      add_pie(hole = 0.4)%>%
      layout(xaxis = list(zeroline = F,
                          showline = F,
                          showticklabels = F,
                          showgrid = F),
             yaxis = list(zeroline = F,
                          showline = F,
                          showticklabels=F,
                          showgrid=F))   })
```

Comment: I guess the easiest way to solve this is to put a condition inside the render function/call to generate (or only label) a plot with either percent or absolute values and display (you could use a radion button input to select wheather it should be percent or absolute values) or you could have distinct buttons for rendering with relative and absolute values... generating a button to interact with the plot from inside plotly seems to be a rather complex task (probably more than R code needed for this)

Comment: also this is a shiny and plotly related question - not dplyr... I just editted the tags of your question accordingly

Comment: I just did. I added the radiobutton on the ui, defining the choices = c("value", "percent"), then later on the server I just assign textinfo = input$radiobutton, and is working. Thanks

Comment: great solution to avoid and if statement - consider to post it as answer to your own question ans accept it - you will gain points, a medal and help future visitors with it

Answer (score 0):

I added the radiobutton on the ui, defining the choices = c("value", "percent"), then later on the server I just assign textinfo = input$radiobutton.
and done!!!
Thanks